# Changing the format to a plot ticks (using pgfplots)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

Dera all:

I'm using `pgfplots` to plot the data from the table below (forst vs. fourth column),

```
3000              1.2970e+00    0.198956 0.258046
3100              8.6050e-01    0.18747 0.161318
3200              5.7970e-01    0.172414 0.0999484
3300              3.9770e-01    0.147098 0.0585009
3400              2.7720e-01    0.128355 0.03558
3500              1.9700e-01    0.139395 0.0274608
3600              1.4310e-01    0.0867237 0.0124102
3700              1.0600e-01    0.0865613 0.0091755
3800              7.9990e-02    0.0509629 0.00407652
3900              6.1560e-02    0.0501454 0.00308695
4000              4.8010e-02    0.0249455 0.00119763
```

It's almost perfect, the only thing that is bothering me is that the `x`-axis ticks are written as `3,000`, `3,100` and so on.

**QUESTION:**

How could I avoid the comma in the ticks?

**My code**

Here it is!

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,units,xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!H]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis background/.style={
          shade,top color=gray,bottom color=white},
        legend style={fill=white},xlabel=Mass $\Omega$,ylabel=$\sigma*\mathcal{A}(\unit{pb})$]
      \addplot+[only marks] table[x index=0,y index=3,header=false] {Table.dat};
      \legend{$\sigma_{\text{MC}}$}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{plot with data}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

**And the result**

[image: Resulting plot from the code]

Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `/pgf/number format/set thousands separator` key. See the `pgfmanual`, (section 66, Number printing). Due to popular demand, I replaced the `units` package by `siunitx`. For picobarn, you need to type `\si{\pico\barn}` instead of `\unit{pb}`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfkeys{%
    /pgf/number format/set thousands separator = {}}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis background/.style = {%
      shade,
      top color = gray,
      bottom color = white},
    legend style = {%
      fill = white},
    xlabel = Mass $\Omega$,
    ylabel = $\sigma*\mathcal{A}(\si{\pico\barn})$,
    ]
    \addplot+[only marks] table[x index=0,y index=3,header=false] {%
     3000              1.2970e+00    0.198956 0.258046
     3100              8.6050e-01    0.18747 0.161318
     3200              5.7970e-01    0.172414 0.0999484
     3300              3.9770e-01    0.147098 0.0585009
     3400              2.7720e-01    0.128355 0.03558
     3500              1.9700e-01    0.139395 0.0274608
     3600              1.4310e-01    0.0867237 0.0124102
     3700              1.0600e-01    0.0865613 0.0091755
     3800              7.9990e-02    0.0509629 0.00407652
     3900              6.1560e-02    0.0501454 0.00308695
     4000              4.8010e-02    0.0249455 0.00119763
   };
    \legend{$\sigma_{\text{MC}}$}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you very much, and for the `siunitx` package! Cheers